# laravel 6.0 belongsTo with ApplicationService

Tags: laravel, eloquent, belongs-to

I'm new in laravel framework. I couldn't get work medicine with prices in controller.

My model;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Medicine extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'medicine';
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $guarded  = [];

    public function withPrice()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MedicinePrice', 'medicine_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

In my app service ;

```
    public function getRecentEntries()
    {
        $medicines = Medicine::orderBy('id','DESC')->take(10)->get()->toArray();
        dd($medicines);
        return $this->formatMedicine($medicines);
    }
```

Table of medicine : https://take.ms/EHrwd
Table of medicine_price : https://take.ms/BMTJW

Any helps ? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never loading the relationship in your code. You can accomplish it with:

```php
Medicine::with('withPrice')->get();
```

However, the `with('withPrice')` sounds a little weird doesn't it? I would recommend you to rename the method of your relation in your Medicine model to something prettier, like `prices`:

```php
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MedicinePrice::class);
}
```

And then you can retrieve the medicine with the prices like this:

```php
$medicines = Medicine::with('prices')->orderByDesc('id')->take(10)->get()->toArray();
```

You can read more about eager loading here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @FatihToprak No problem! Glad you understand it now! :)

Comment: hello again :) i have one more question, ```public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MedicineCategoryMapping::class);
    }

    public function activeMatter()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(MedicineActiveMatterMapping::class);
    }``` this is some relations, the question is, how could i get other relational data from another model ? (in this code, category relation) Screenshot : https://take.ms/hQoZl

Comment: @FatihToprak A has many returns a `Collection` instance. Therefore you either have to loop through the collection or retrieve the first model. `$this->category->first()`